# Apply Visio Theme selectively by tab in Visio 2016

Tags: themes, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

I  have a drawing that has hand-selected colors and I want to retain those colors while I'm creating a new diagram with a theme.  When I apply a theme to the new tab, it converts the original to all one color, making it hard to work with.

Is there a way to tell Visio to not apply any themes to one tab, but apply it to another?

Answer (score 1):

Before you apply the theme, select all the shapes then right-click -> **Remove Theme**.